# Add custom tooltip for x axis label on hover action

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

In our Angular application we are using Highcharts. In that we are showing xAxis labeles as below

[image]

When the number of items are more and we have long text, we are showing part of the text and want to show tooltip/tilte on hover like below.

[image]

I tried something like below:

```
this.chartOptions.xAxis['labels'].events.mouseover = (e) => {
    e.chart.renderer.label("tooltip text", e.x, e.y, 'rectangle').css({
    color: '#FFFFFF'
})
.attr({
    fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    padding: 8,
    r: 4,
})
.add()
.toFront();
}
```

But, here the problem is the event does not have any renderer in it. So, not able to add the custom label.

I have also tried multiple ways using `axisTitle`, `formatter` etc.. (Please check [this link](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=46946&p=169464) for reference)

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Use a basic function instead of an arrow one and refer to a chart by `this` keyword:

```
mouseover: function(e) {
    this.chart.renderer.label("tooltip text", e.x, e.y, 'rectangle').css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        })
        .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 4,
        })
        .add()
        .toFront();
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfazcwyr/